# Evaluate controller after directive has been resolved in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angularjs.

I have a directive that uses a promise to get a remote json to generate the template. The directive renders table columns.

I have a table with a controller that get remote data using a promise.

How can I be sure that the template that renders the columns is ready before the table try to render data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one or both promises in the Parent and use binding to send a reference of the promise to the child:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/77pWLnIbvBx9HipwtwR7?p=preview)

```
app.directive('parent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope, $q) {
            $scope.tablePromise = $q.when();
        }
    }
});

app.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            promise: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.promise.then(renderColumns)
        }
    }
});
```